# Remote dev for Symfony 2 app

Tags: symfony, development-environment, remote-server

Is there a proper way to develop an app on a remote server with Symfony 2 ?

I use API calls, so I think I have to remote dev to prevent errors with non local ajax or curl calls. Am I wrong, that is to say, can I do it on a local server ?

Answer (score 0):

I found it is easier to code with a local server command line applications with API Calls.

Of course a VPS could do better but I did not try.

All the best.